# X-Drupal-Cache is missing from HTTP headers

Tags: 7, caching, cookies

X-Drupal-Cache seems to be missing from HTTP headers. The funny thing is that, when I cleared my cookies, it reappears twice: once with a "MISS" and then with a "HIT". After that, X-Drupal-Cache disappears again.

Is this normal?

Comment: Hello. You stated a fact. Now please ask a question. Note that we will not be able to debug your site for you. We will not be able to fix bugs in existing projects, either.

Comment: Hi, I'm actually asking if this is normal.